# Try to get the question reopened or should I just delete it?

Tags: support

I posted this question because I believed it to be relevant to professional system administration. Yes, I am the user, but I am also a systems engineer/programmer and I couldn't figure out how to solve this (yes me) end user's problem:

[Connecting to a computer via remote desktop, which is connected to VPN](https://serverfault.com/questions/644396/connecting-to-a-computer-via-remote-desktop-which-is-connected-to-vpn)

So, I can reword this question from the perspective that I am the systems engineer and not the end user and this should make the question OK, right?

As I believe this question is relevant and add value, I don't believe it should be deleted.

What should I do?

Answer (score 11):

Personally I don't think the question should be reopened.

**1. You received your answer**
For all intents and purposes, the issue is now resolved.

**2. The answer was readily available in product documentation**
The resolution to the question was the same as opening up the manual and ctrl+f to LAN or Local.
Honestly this is a well documented functionality of most VPN clients, and you should have been aware of it. (Especially when after only 2 minutes the first comment immediatly gave you the answer, and an hour later you had a full-on screen shotted tutorial in the answers.)

**3. The community decided to close it**
And maybe most importantly, your question wasn't closed by a single mod (and even if it was...).
Your question was voted to be closed because multiple people thought it was off-topic.
Fine you could change the wording, but it's still a problem for end-users.

I'm fairly certain if you had known that your issue was with your clients routing of local lan, you would have [found it on google's first hit](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/70847-local-lan-pix-asa.html#anc9). (Maybe not the best article to pick, but it was my first google hit, and it had the answer, so I'm sticking by it)

Answer (score 10):

In addition to [the points Reaces made](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/6824/32986), I would add a fourth:

**This question does not appear to be related to professional system *administration*.**
The way your question is currently phrased you are a user attempting to accomplish a task, and should be asking *your site system administrator* for assistance, not Server Fault.
This is probably why your question was closed.

---

Now you very well may also be your site's system administrator as you noted above, but if that's the case  **you should not be asking the question as a user**.
Rephrase your question in the third person ("One of my users is trying to…"), and it's more obviously in scope for this site.  You should also tell us what documentation you've consulted & what steps you've tried on your own to troubleshoot/resolve the issue, though in this case the question is already answered so there's no real need to do that.

This may seem like pointless nitpicking, but I assure you the sheer volume of crap we get from folks who don't want to talk to their system administrator and expect Server Fault to act as Free Technical Support For The Interwebs justifies a little nitpicking.

If you edit your question to address the issue above it will automatically be placed in a queue to be evaluated for reopening.

Comment: `the sheer volume of crap we get from folks who don't want to talk to their system administrator and expect Server Fault to act as Free Technical Support For The Interwebs justifies a little nitpicking`  It justifies a lot more than just a little nitpicking too, I'll add.  Like I told the judge, it justifies homicide as well, but I think he may have been asking rhetorically, now that I look back on it.

Comment: Oh, my, yes.  Yaaay HopelessN00b.  HN for moderator!  And voretaq7, too!  (Oh, wait...)